# Error when running VS2010 - visual c# command line compiler has stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

When I'm running VS2010 - It shows this error "visual c# command line compiler has stopped working" alert.

Comment: This appears to be a technical question, related to http://superuser.com/.

Please create a question there and provide more information, like OS used, VS plugins used and anything that could help.

Comment: Someone else seems to had the same issue and it turned out to be a virus. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/visual-c-command-line-compiler-has-stopped-working/1484b5d1-7e98-4cf9-990e-0af00d2292ad.

Comment: Looks like your compiler is 'broken'. Try repairing Visual Studio, the Windows SDK's you have installed (in order of version) and applying SP1 to Visual Studio and any updates that were released after that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/23/keeping-your-tfs-2010-up-to-date-as-of-march-2012.aspx

Comment: It shows this msg too: "The instruction at 0x7520966f referenced memory at 0x002789b0. The memory could not be read. Click OK to terminate the program.
click on Cancle to debug the program."